# Finding the crash location inside NPAPI plugin in Chrome

Tags: visual-studio, google-chrome-extension, npapi, browser-plugin

I've got an NPAPI plugin that works successfully on Chrome, Firefox, etc., except for one user, where it crashes in Chrome, but not in Firefox. I've installed Visual Studio on that user's machine, have downloaded the source files for my plugin, and am trying to debug the crash. I can attach to the appropriate chrome.exe process (thank you `--plugin-startup-dialog`), can set breakpoints, and can walk through my code. But there are several hundred thousand lines of code to debug, code that gets called multiple time a second, and I haven't found the right breakpoint yet.

Normally, of course, when a process VS is debugging crashes, VS will report the crash, and give you the chance to look at the call stack. But with Chrome, the crash apparently never gets reported to VS, as the process just exits silently.

[I'm told](http://pushingtheweb.com/2010/06/debugging-npapi-plugins-in-visual-studio/) that you can disable the equivalent behavior in Firefox, so that VS can handle the error, but I'm not sure how to do this in Chrome. Any ideas about how to get the crash reported to Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to start it with `--disable-breakpad`?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I was misdiagnosing the issue. There was an aggressive security application on the machine in question. It thought our NPAPI plugin was doing something inappropriate (calling `SetWindowsHookEx`), and so was silently killing the Chrome process that hosted the plugin. I suspect that VS would have seen *some* sort of exception under normal circumstances.